# How to Add User Input in the Dictionary's First (or Specific) Key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, key-value-store

I just began learning Python 3 and this is my first few codes i started writing. This will ask the user to add a dictionary:

```
add_d = input("Add Dictionary: ")
```

Then it will ask the user to add values and add them to the first (or specific) key of the dictionary

```
add_item = str(input("Add value: ")
for x in add_d():
     add_d.keys()[x] = add_item
```

My problem is that the error "dict object is not callable" appears.
How do i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things that don't quite work with this. The error message relates to `for x in add_d()` (you should remove the `()` because it isn't a function call). But you should remember that a dictionary is a series of `key:value` pairs so you would really want the user to specify a key and a value, rather than a dictionary and a value. That would look more like this

```
add_d = dict()
dict_key = input("Specify key: ")
dict_val = input("Specify value: ")
add_d[dict_key] = dict_value
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like a problem in the un-closed parenthesis :

```
add_item = str(input("Add value: "))
for x in add_d():
     add_d.keys()[x] = add_item
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the variable add_d as a function which is not, that's why it is displaying object not callable.
You can use the fromkeys method to create a dictionary with the keys and values entered.

```
add_d = input("Add Dictionary: ")
add_item = input("Add value: ")
add_d = dict.fromkeys(add_d, add_item)
print(add_d)
output: {key: value}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are a few issues in your example

1. `input("Add Dictionary: ")` will return str never be dict
2. `add_item = str(input("Add value: "))` does not need `str()` because it is string
3. Because `add_d` is string,then it can't use `add_d.keys()`.(only dict can do this)

I guessed you want:

```
d = {}
while 1:
    add_d = input("Add key: ")
    if not add_d:
        break
    add_item = input("Add value: ")
    d[add_d] = add_item 
print(d)
```